# SQL Server 2012 query date

Tags: sql-server, join

How can I return values in a where clause for something like this:

Get me all the records that exist in table1.de1,table2.de2,table3.de3,table4.de3

```
select * 
from table1
inner join table2
on table2.carID = table1.carID
inner join table3
on table3.carID = table1.carID
inner join table4
on table4.driverID = table1.driverID
```

where a `recietrecord` exists in `table2` and its `paydate` has passed 20 days ago, comparing it to TODAYS date and show those days in a field called `Days Passed From The Day Driver Was Suppose To Pay`

Comment: You could probably use a `DateDiff(dd, paydate, getdate())` in your select clause to show the day difference. 

In the where clause, you could have a where `DateDiff(dd, paydate, getdate()) < 0` or something appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please, use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx). This solution is for **SQL Server**:

As was written in comments you can use [DATEDIFF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx) function to compare `paydate` to [GETDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx).

```
select  *,
        DATEDIFF(day,t2.paydate,GETDATE()) as [Days Passed From The Day Driver Was Suppose To Pay]
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t2.carID = t1.carID
inner join table3 t3
    on t3.carID = t1.carID
inner join table4 t4
    on t4.driverID = t1.driverID
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,t2.paydate,GETDATE()) > 20
```

Or better use minutes:

```
DATEDIFF(minute,t2.paydate,GETDATE()) > 28800 --60 minutes * 24 hours * 20 days
```